# Java Swing : creating frame in ActionPerformed() of different class

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt, java-7

I have first frame containing a button. On pressing the button I invoke actionPerformed() method of different class.

```
JButton compress = new JButton("Submit");
compress.addActionListener(new Action1(inp,out,frame1)); // inp,out are textboxes and frame1 is 1st frame containing textboxes and JButton
```

In actionPerformed() of class Action1. I have created another frame there as follows

```
static class Action1 implements ActionListener {        

        JTextField input_path,out_path;
        JFrame prev;

        public Action1(JTextField inp,JTextField out,JFrame jf)
        {
            input_path = inp;
            out_path = out;
            prev = jf;
        }

        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {           
            prev.dispose();
            try{
                drawFrame();
                // launch the compression job
                launchJob(input_path.getText(),out_path.getText());
            }
            catch(IOException io){
                io.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        public void drawFrame()
        {
            JFrame frame2 = new JFrame("New Frame");
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();

            frame2.setSize(400,300);
            frame2.setLocation(500, 300);
            JLabel label = new JLabel(" in Progress...");

            panel.add(label);
            frame2.add(panel);
            frame2.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
```

But in actionPerformed(), the contents of the frame2 are getting visible after method launchJob() is executed. I want to display(make visible) content of frame2 before my function launchJob() starts executing. Can you plz suggest where im going wrong or some alternative. Thank you.

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Answer (score 0):

I have just verified that your frame is being set visible *before* your method *launchJob()* is called.

Consider adding some print statements to debug, for example, at the end of the *drawFrame()* method , add the following code:

```
frame2.setVisible(true);
System.out.println("frame visible");
```

Do the same at the start of the launch job method:

```
System.out.println("doing launch job");
```

You will see that the output is:

```
frame visible
doing launch job
```

This verifies that the JFrame *is* in fact being made visible before your launch job method.

Comment: JFrame is getting visible but the content(panel ,label "in progress") of Jframe is visible  after the launchJob() method has completed...can u tell me abt that plz...

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @Sumit: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20901770/2711488), especially the answers to point 4.